# tool analysis software evolution

Tags: testing, analytics, code-analysis

Let's consider that there are target programs. For each target program, there is a correspondent test program. Target programs are evolving independently. However, the test programs are evolving according to the target programs. Let's consider pairs formed from (target program, test).

Making the problem general, two programs are evolving in parallel, with one being dependent on another. Consider only this general case, not the particular case with tests.

It is there an existing tool, framework or research that is analyzing the evolution of these pairs of programs? As an example, is there a tool or research that analyze the evolution of test programs w.r.t. their target programs?

Thank you for any suggestion/link !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestEvol is such a tool. Reference the paper from http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~orso/papers/pinto.sinha.orso.ICSE12.pdf .